# Multiple Inputs in ne mongoose method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have users collection and I would like to get all users **where** status **doesn't equal** 'deleted' **or** 'pending'

I tried this

```
users.find().where('status').ne('deleted').where('status').ne('pending')
```

but it doesn't work.

I also tried this

```
users.find().where('status').ne(['deleted','pending'])
```

Also doesn't work.

How would I accomplish it?

I know it can be accomplished using a nested query string, but I want a way with the help of these query methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do multiple $ne then do

```
users.find({status: {$nin : ["deleted", "pending"]}})
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/